# bxSlider full width avoid horizontal scroll on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

I using template with bootstrap 3 and like to use bxSlider (http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1) plugged into the page. I wanted to make the slider in full width (removed the div 'container' class), however, the horizontal scroll-bar is appear when I was applied on it. Please take a look on my css on how to prevent this little glitch, attached with screenshot.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Fixed Height Image Aside -->
<!-- Image backgrounds are set within the full-width-pics.css file. -->
<aside class="image-bg-fixed-height2">
    <!--<div class="container">-->
    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="bx-pager" class="bx-pager">
                <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/thumb/pic1.jpg" /></a>
                <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/thumb/pic2.jpg" /></a>
                <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/thumb/pic3.jpg" /></a>
                <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="<?php echo baseurl ?>/images/thumb/pic4.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</aside>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .bx-wrapper {
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 0 auto 60px;*/
    margin: 0 auto 0px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border:  5px solid #fff;
    left: -5px;*/
    left: 0;
    background: #353535;

    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(../images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color:#000;margin:0;padding:20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 25px;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 25px;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}


/*custom - http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/create-a-responsive-slider-with-the-bxslider-jquery-plugin/*/
ul.bxslider{
    margin:0;
}

#bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000;
    padding: 16px;
}

#bx-pager img {
    padding: 5px;
}

#bx-pager a:active, 
#bx-pager a.active {
    border: 2px #FF0000 solid;
}
```

Comment: you have a closing div for .container that is not there. If you use a .row you must use either .container or .container-fluid to wrap it, if it expands the full width of the page, you need no .row or col classes to do so. See: Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

i got this problem so best solution

```
body { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use bootstrap row, if you use your row it fixed.

`class="myrow"` and css:

```
.myrow{ width:100%; margin:0; paddding:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `.contrainer` to `.contrainer-fluid`

Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.